# Unable to set PATH

Tags: windows

When I execute below command in Windows 7 prompt

```
D:>set path "%path%;C:\Users\P7165379\AppData\Roaming\npm"
```

It shows below message

```
 Environment variable path "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program 
 Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS 
 Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Syst
 Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files 
 (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program 
 Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nod
 cmd;C:\Users\P7165379\.dnx\bin;C:\Users\P7165379\AppData\Roaming\npm" not 
defined
```

Any idea what is the issue.

Comment: Drop the quotation marks.

Comment: you mean to say just, set path %path%;C:\Users\P7165379\AppData\Roaming\npm , this also not working

Comment: You also forgot the equals sign. Are you just making up the syntax as you go along, or did you look it up somewhere? `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\P7165379\AppData\Roaming\npm` works fine.

Comment: I am sorry , my mistake , it's working.. thanks